# Check whether a particular field's value is changed

Tags: node.js, podio

I'm using **Podio** for day to day tasks and I'm getting data using `podio-js`. I want to check whether a value is changed in a field. Is there API method or anyway to check  whether a particular field's value is changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can add field level hook for an app. 
Reference : https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks

You can't add a field hook as we normally add hook through the UI. You need to use the podio API to add field level hook.

you can use create hook API. 
Reference : https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/create-hook-215056

in this you need to pass `type` as `"app_field"` and
`ref_id` as `field id`

Thsi hook will fire only when the specified field is updated.